# Export SVM model to PMML using Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, pmml

I am applying SVM algorithm using Scikit-Learn to predict whether a Customer will opt for a Home Loan or not. I want the model to be exported into PMML format. The features and labels in the dataset are shown below:
**Features** 
1. Frequency of visits  
2. Response to offers
3. Usage of online banking facility
4. Number of savings account
5. Number of checking account
6. Number of checks written
7. Number of EFTs done
8. Property acquired
9. Other Loans Behaviour
10. Income

**Label**
Is House Loan

The model is generated properly, but it can't be exported into PMML. The code is pasted below:
**Code:**

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

from sklearn2pmml.decoration import ContinuousDomain

import pandas
import sklearn_pandas
from sklearn.svm import SVC



home_loan = pandas.read_csv('home-loan-dataset.csv')

home_loan = home_loan.drop(['CustID'], axis=1)

home_loan_df = pandas.concat((pandas.DataFrame(home_loan[:], columns = ['Frequencyofvisits','Responsetooffers','UsageofOnlineBankingFacility','Numberofsavingsaccount','Numberofcheckingaccount','Numberofcheckswritten','NumberofEFTsdone','PropertyAcquired','OtherLoansBehaviour','Income']), pandas.DataFrame(home_loan['IsHouseLoan'], columns = ["IsHouseLoan"])), axis = 1)

home_loan_mapper = sklearn_pandas.DataFrameMapper([
    (['Frequencyofvisits','Responsetooffers','UsageofOnlineBankingFacility','Numberofsavingsaccount','Numberofcheckingaccount','Numberofcheckswritten','NumberofEFTsdone','PropertyAcquired','OtherLoansBehaviour','Income'], [ContinuousDomain(), PCA(n_components = 3)]),
    ("IsHouseLoan", None)
])


home_loan = home_loan_df


home_loan_X = home_loan[['Frequencyofvisits','Responsetooffers','UsageofOnlineBankingFacility','Numberofsavingsaccount','Numberofcheckingaccount','Numberofcheckswritten','NumberofEFTsdone','PropertyAcquired','OtherLoansBehaviour','Income']]

home_loan_y = home_loan[['IsHouseLoan']]

# Classify using SVM

home_loan_classifier = SVC()



home_loan_classifier.fit(home_loan_X, home_loan_y.values.ravel())

SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
    decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
    max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
    tol=0.001, verbose=False)



#
# Conversion to PMML
#

from sklearn2pmml import sklearn2pmml

sklearn2pmml(home_loan_classifier, home_loan_mapper, "SVMHomeLoan.pmml", with_repr = True)
```

The following error is displayed while converting to PMML:
**Error:**

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/ML-Programs/Bank-Customer-Segmentation/svm-pmml.py
Aug 17, 2016 11:35:01 AM org.jpmml.sklearn.Main run
INFO: Parsing DataFrameMapper PKL..
Aug 17, 2016 11:35:01 AM org.jpmml.sklearn.Main run
INFO: Parsed DataFrameMapper PKL in 30 ms.
Aug 17, 2016 11:35:01 AM org.jpmml.sklearn.Main run
INFO: Converting DataFrameMapper..
Aug 17, 2016 11:35:01 AM org.jpmml.sklearn.Main run
SEVERE: Failed to convert DataFrameMapper
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value of the sklearn2pmml.decoration.ContinuousDomain.data_min_ attribute (null) is not a supported array type
    at org.jpmml.sklearn.ClassDictUtil.getArray(ClassDictUtil.java:51)
    at sklearn2pmml.decoration.ContinuousDomain.getDataMin(ContinuousDomain.java:111)
    at sklearn2pmml.decoration.ContinuousDomain.encodeFeatures(ContinuousDomain.java:50)
    at sklearn_pandas.DataFrameMapper.encodeFeatures(DataFrameMapper.java:70)
    at org.jpmml.sklearn.Main.run(Main.java:146)
    at org.jpmml.sklearn.Main.main(Main.java:107)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value of the sklearn2pmml.decoration.ContinuousDomain.data_min_ attribute (null) is not a supported array type
    at org.jpmml.sklearn.ClassDictUtil.getArray(ClassDictUtil.java:51)
    at sklearn2pmml.decoration.ContinuousDomain.getDataMin(ContinuousDomain.java:111)
    at sklearn2pmml.decoration.ContinuousDomain.encodeFeatures(ContinuousDomain.java:50)
    at sklearn_pandas.DataFrameMapper.encodeFeatures(DataFrameMapper.java:70)
    at org.jpmml.sklearn.Main.run(Main.java:146)
    at org.jpmml.sklearn.Main.main(Main.java:107)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/ML-Programs/Bank-Customer-Segmentation/svm-pmml.py", line 52, in <module>
    sklearn2pmml(home_loan_classifier, home_loan_mapper, "SVMHomeLoan.pmml", with_repr = True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn2pmml\__init__.py", line 56, in sklearn2pmml
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-cp', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn2pmml\\resources\\guava-19.0.jar;C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn2pmml\\resources\\istack-commons-runtime-2.21.jar;C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn2pmml\\resources\\jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar;C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn2pmml\\resources\\jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar;C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn2pmml\\resources\\jcommander-1.48.jar;C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn2pmml\\resources\\jpmml-converter-1.0.7.jar;C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn2pmml\\resources\\jpmml-sklearn-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn2pmml\\resources\\jpmml-xgboost-1.0.5.jar;C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn2pmml\\resources\\pmml-agent-1.2.16.jar;C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn2pmml\\resources\\pmml-model-1.2.16.jar;C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn2pmml\\resources\\pmml-model-metro-1.2.16.jar;C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn2pmml\\resources\\pmml-schema-1.2.16.jar;C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn2pmml\\resources\\pyrolite-4.12.jar;C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn2pmml\\resources\\serpent-1.12.jar;C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn2pmml\\resources\\slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar;C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn2pmml\\resources\\slf4j-jdk14-1.7.21.jar', 'org.jpmml.sklearn.Main', '--pkl-estimator-input', 'c:\\users\\Admin\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmplgmrjq.pkl', '--repr-estimator', "SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,\n  decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',\n  max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,\n  tol=0.001, verbose=False)", '--pkl-mapper-input', 'c:\\users\\Admin\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpobahse.pkl', '--repr-mapper', "DataFrameMapper(features=[(['Frequencyofvisits', 'Responsetooffers', 'UsageofOnlineBankingFacility', 'Numberofsavingsaccount', 'Numberofcheckingaccount', 'Numberofcheckswritten', 'NumberofEFTsdone', 'PropertyAcquired', 'OtherLoansBehavior', 'Income100000'], TransformerPipeline(steps=[('continuousdomain', ContinuousDomain(invalid_value_treatment='return_invalid')), ('pca', PCA(copy=True, n_components=3, whiten=False))])), ('IsHouseLoan', None)],\n        sparse=False)", '--pmml-output', 'SVMHomeLoan.pmml']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

**What could be the reason ?**

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, one of your data columns does not meet the expectations of the `sklearn2pmml.decoration.ContinuousDomain` transformation. It's impossible to say which column, and what is the exact nature of the problem (eg. categorical operational type instead of continuous, wrong numeric data type, **column contains NA values**, etc.) without seeing your data.

You have two options here:

1. Identify the misbehaving column, and fix the data issue so that the `ContinuousDomain` transformation works OK.
2. Exclude the `ContinuousDomain` from the list transformations list.

At the moment you're using data pre-processing logic that has been directly copied from sklearn2pmml README.md file. Please re-work it to match you data - it's unlikely that the `[ContinuousDomain(), PCA(n_components = 3)]` transformation is the right solution for your use case.

Also, this issue is rather specific to the [sklearn2pmml](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) package. You're likely to get better/faster replies if you opened an issue in sklearn2pmml issue tracker.